# php login system not working

Tags: php, sql, authentication

Hi I have this piece of code but whenever I enter any username or password whether right or wrong, it just shows the code inside the else block. I would really appreciate any help.

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
$username=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$username=trim($POST['email']);
$username=stripslashes($POST['email']);
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($POST['email']);
$password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$password=trim($_POST['password']);
$password=stripslashes($_POST['password']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

}
mysql_select_db ($db,$dbconnect);
$check="SELECT * FROM students WHERE (username='$username') AND (password='$password')    
LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($check);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if ($count==1)
{
$_SESSION[$username];
$_SESSION[$password];
header ('Location: attendance.php');
exit ();

}
else
{
echo "wrong password or username";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you run your query from the command line? Do you get any errors? You don't check for errors in your code so that would explain why you don't see any.

Comment: If there are two users with same name and password, $count would be ==2 and you will see "else" anyways.

Comment: Never, *never*, ***never*** store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Your `htmlspecialchars`, `trim`, and `stripslashes` calls are utterly useless. You're pulling data from the SAME source for each, then trashing the results on the very next call.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using mysqli or better PDO as mysql has been deprecated but try this.

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{

    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($POST['email']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    mysql_select_db ($db,$dbconnect);
    $check="SELECT * FROM students WHERE (username='$username') AND (password='$password')    
    LIMIT 1";
    $result=mysql_query($check);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

}


if (isset($count) && $count == 1)
{
    $_SESSION[$username];
    $_SESSION[$password];
    header ('Location: attendance.php');
    exit ();

}
else
{
    echo "wrong password or username";
}
?>
```

Comment: I would have to say I am a newbie to php so I am just testing this out and will definitely include all the changes including encrypting passwords, sanitizing the input fields,etc that are all written down in the comments in the original script. It is working now. Thank you guys!